# Neighborhoods in product spaces

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Consider the infinite product space where each component is the real numbers with the Euclidean topology and $p = (1,1,1,...)$. Show or disprove that $\forall U \ni p, \exists t > 0, \forall s \in (1, 1+t), (s,s,s,...) \in U$. I'm not really sure where to begin here, any hints would be appreciated, thanks!

Edit: Forgot to clarify I'm using the product topology as opposed to the box.

Comment: What topology are you using on this infinite product?

Comment: @TedShifrin Whoops, thanks for pointing that out I forgot to mention; the product topology.

Comment: Here's a question for you. Would the statement be true if you had the product of $2$ copies of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @TedShifrin It would be, right, since you can use the $t$ from the Euclidean ball?

Comment: Think of a rectangle rather than of a ball. OK, so can you generalize to a rectangle in $\Bbb R^n$? Now what?

Comment: @TedShifrin My instinct would be that the statement would also hold. I'm not really sure how to show it though, I'm having a lot of trouble kind of understanding product topologies.

Comment: So you see what to write down for the rectangle in $\Bbb R^n$? Now, what does an basis element for the product topology look like?

Comment: Ok, so since $p \in U$, $p \in \prod_{i \in N} U_{i}$, where all but finitely many of the $U_{i}$ are $\mathbb{R}$. Each of the $U_{i}$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ and so is an open interval or a union of open intervals

Comment: So you already told me you knew how to solve it when you had a finite rectangle, and there's no issue with the other factors, right? ...  But with the box topology, couldn't you have shrinking sides in your infinite-dimensional box?

Comment: I think I understand now. So since there's a finite number of $U_{i}$ in the product topology, we can take the minimum of them and use that as our $\epsilon$ so the statement holds. If we're in the box topology, then because there's an infinite number of $\epsilon$, their minimum might be 0, so we can't guarantee the statement.

Comment: Perfect, @BalsamicVinegar.

Comment: @BalsamicVinegar yes, you got it. Now, for comparison, take the box topology and try to repeat the argument.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that it's a product with index set $\Bbb N$.  That is you are talking about $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$.  There are other products.  For instance, uncountable ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True, since in the product topology open sets are of the form $\prod_{i\in \Bbb N}U_i$, where $U_i=\Bbb R$ for all but finitely many $i$.  Each of the $U_i$ is either of the form $(1-\epsilon_i,1+\epsilon_i)$ or equal to $\Bbb R$.

Let $t=\operatorname{glb}\{\epsilon_i:U_i\ne\Bbb R\}$.

Then consider $(1+t/2,1+t/2,\dots)$.

Comment: That's a bit too simplistic, although the right flavor.

Comment: So would the statement not hold in the box topology then?

Comment: The statement would hold in the box topology too.

Comment: @TedShifrin I agree.  I've added something.

Comment: Cool. But in the box topology, the glb of that set could very well be $0$.

Comment: You're right.  I'll have to think about it more. @TedShifrin

Comment: So let $U_i=(1-1/i,1+1/i)$.  Then it's no. @TedShifrin

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** A basis open set for the product topology is of the form $\prod_{i\in I\text{ finite}}U_i\times \prod_{i\in \mathbf{N}-I} \mathbf{R}$, where $U_i\subset \mathbf{R}$ is open. An open set in the product topology is the union of basis open sets.

Let $U$ be an open set in the product topology that contains $p$, then $p$ is contained in some basis open set. Can you continue?

Comment: Do we have to use the fact that there's finite $U_{i}$?

Comment: @BalsamicVinegar: Yes: see Ted Shifrin’s last comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $p$.

Then there exists a basic open neighbourhood of $p$, namely $\prod_n U_n$, such that $p \in \prod_n U_n \subseteq U$, where there is a finite subset $F$ of $\Bbb N$ such that $U_n$ is a proper open subset of $\Bbb R$ (containing $1$) for $n \in F$ and $U_n = \Bbb R$ for $n \notin F$.

For every $n \in F$ pick $r_n >0$ such that $(1-r_n, 1+r_n) \subseteq U_n$, by openness of $U_n$.

Let $t=\min_{n \in F} r_n >0$. (Note that we have a finite set, so the minimum is well-defined and $>0$.)

Then for $s \in (1,1+t)$ we see that $\underline{s}=(s,s,s,\ldots) \in \prod_n U_n $: if $n \in F$, then $1 < s < 1+t \le 1+r_n$, so $s \in (1-r_n,1+r_n) \subseteq U_n$ and if $n \notin F$, $s \in U_n=\Bbb R$ is trivial.

So $t$ is as required.